# Add div for 2 times only using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, append

I want to append a div(chunk of code ) onclick of a link up to 2 times only. After appending second time, I want to hide the link "add more provider".

My present code : [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Hk6Ch/)

```
 $('#addProviderLink').click(function(e) {

    var addProviderDiv = $('<div class="formData"><strong><label>Additional Provider</label></strong><input type="text" class="ac_input width226" value="" /><span class="f11"><a href="#" class="underline removeThis">Delete</a></span> </div>');

       $('.addProContainer').append(addProviderDiv);
  });
$('.removeThis').live('click', function(){
    $(this).parent().parent().remove(); 
});
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Hk6Ch/9/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

USe a counter for it

```
    var count = 0;
$('#addProviderLink').click(function (e) {
    count++;
    if (count == 2) {
        $("#addProviderLink").hide();
    }
    var addProviderDiv = $('<div class="formData"><strong><label>Additional Provider</label></strong><input type="text" class="ac_input width226" value="" /><span class="f11"><a href="#" class="underline removeThis">Delete</a></span> </div>');

    $('.addProContainer').append(addProviderDiv);
});
```

**Edit**

```
$('.removeThis').live('click', function(){
    count--;
    $(this).parent().parent().remove(); 
    $("#addProviderLink").show(); 
});
```

[**updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Hk6Ch/13/)

Comment: yes this is what i want but that add more provider link should be back on place if I remove both added divs.

Comment: @Era Have a look at my Answer for  that.

Comment: @AnoopJoshi: why do you have to make this complicated.

Comment: @MilindAnantwar : Your answer is incomplete for my query. Although that could be a better way to do this but cant use.

Comment: @Era: i have already commented about this approach in one of the answer below.

Comment: @MilindAnantwar : Yes, i read. But requesting you to complete your answer as per my query, so that i can actually use that.

Comment: @Era: have you checked the fiddle in DEMO. what else you require.

Comment: @MilindAnantwar No need to get feisty. Yours still doesn't work. From the original request: "I want to hide the link..." We can argue about the best way to do it all night, but please provide a solution that actually works first.

Comment: @gwcoffey: look whom i am arguing with :/

Answer (score 2):

Add the condition to check the length of appended dom:

```
if($('.addProContainer .underline').length<2)
     $('.addProContainer').append(addProviderDiv);
```

This will even work after removing the elements.

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Hk6Ch/8/)**

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your `click()` handler:

```
if ($(".addProContainer .formData").length > 1) {
   $(this).hide()
}
```

And then add this to your `live()` handler:

```
if ($(".addProContainer .formData").length < 2) {
   $('#addProviderLink').show()
}
```

Side Note: `live()` is deprecated. You should do this instead:

```
$(".addProContainer").on("click", ".removeThis", function() {
   ...
});
```

Here be the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gwcoffey/U52ZG/1/

Comment: `.size()` has been deprecated for several years. Use `.length` instead.